# iPhone Accessory API

Tags: iphone, iphone-accessory

Can anyone give me a short version of what it takes to develop an app which connects to an accessory? I signed up to the 'made for ipod' program and got a huge pile of technical specifications docs which I have no idea how to start with.

Any help would be appreciated.

David

Comment: Did you apply as an individual? The application wants a lot of corporate details, specifically info about the company's legal counsel.

Answer (score 2):

Reading [the accessory section in Apple's iPhone app programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH14-SW20) is probably a great place to start, and includes links to other, more formidable, documentation.